# Android free/paid app using compiler trick

Tags: android

I was wondering whether you could use a trick of the compiler to include different functions for a free and paid version of the app. For instance:

```
public static final boolean paid = false;

if (paid){
    runPaidMethod();
}
else {
    runFreeMethod();
}
```

The compiler will look at that and say that it doesn't need the first branch of the if statement so it won't compile it. Furthermore, it should look at the program and see that `runPaidMethod()` is no longer referenced from anywhere and remove it.

Therefore the question is: is it feasible to just have this flag, compile it once for free, swap the flag then compile it again for paid?

Comment: The JIT works on *bytecode*, the Java compiler works on *source code*.  Which are you talking about?

Comment: If I were to bet I'd translate that as "what is the best way to achieve an ifdef equivalent in java?" :-)

Comment: I guess the Java compiler. I would want the paid methods removed from the free version so that an attacker couldn't de-compile, change the flag to true and then run the paid methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a final boolean variable is good because the Java compiler is smart enough to see that your condition is always false. If you decompile the compiled class (you can try it, with the `javap -c` command) you will see that your code :

```
public static final boolean paid = false;

if (paid) {
    runPaidMethod();
}
else {
    runFreeMethod();
}
```

will be compiled to a single call to :

```
runFreeMethod();
```

The compiler removes any unreachable code, so nobody will be able to reverse engineer your app. But be careful, you have to declare `runPaidMethod()` as a private method, or its content will still appear in the compiled class.

However from a maintenance point of view, it is still better to use [Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) to handle multiple app versions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't this only work if the variable is `final`? I didn't think static had anything to do with it.

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't matter whether it is static or not, I just added that in because that is what I would use.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are trying to express is known as [conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation). In a language like C or C++ you would accomplish this with a combination of preprocessor directives and compiler flags. A rather crude example:

```
#ifdef PAID
    runPaidMethod();
#else
    runFreeMethod();
#endif
```

Good, bad or indifferent, this sort of conditional compilation does not exist in Java. But thats not too say what you are trying to do cannot be accomplished, you just need to think in a more object oriented fashion. One such way of implementing what you are seeking would be to define your major service providers as interfaces, and provide implementations for the paid and free versions. Something like:

```
public interface UsefulService {
    public void someMethod();
    public void otherMethod();
}

public class BaseUsefulService {
   // Common functionality here
   public void otherMethod() {
   }
}

public class FreeUsefulService {
    public void someMethod() {
    }
}

public class PaidUsefulService {
   public void someMethod() {
   }
}
```

With this kind of breakdown you can actually build the paid version of the application into an entirely separate application (by putting all its service providers in a separate project).